# Extra VPS, SPS and PPS before ever I frame slice in h265 in mp4 written by ffmpeg

Tags: c++, video, ffmpeg, hevc

I am trying to generate an mp4 file using ffmpeg containing already encoded H265 data. I am providing the H265 nal units to `av_write_frame` with the VPS, SPS and PPS already in the stream before each I frame.

When I extract the nal units back out of the mp4 file and look at them, there are extra VPS, SPS and PPS before each I frame. For most streams this is inefficient but not a problem, however some of the streams use sliced I frames and the extra nal units are inserted before each slice of the I frame which causes only the first slice to be decodable as the VPS, SPS and PPS are not allowed to be included between slices of the same frame.

We also process H264 video and ffmpeg does not add extra SPS or PPS in front of I frames in H264 streams. We are not providing the VPS, SPS and PPS as side data in the packets, but rather as individual packets for each nal unit. We do use ffmpeg to scan the input to get the codec parameters to use to configure but do not use ffmpeg to encode or decode the video or in any other way process the nal units with ffmpeg.

I have a minimal sample program that shows the issue and have included the code below. We are using different code to load and process the data before passing the data to ffmpeg but I have hard coded the properties of the video for this sample. The video file is available at https://www.dropbox.com/s/eajiowamlkns3ry/stream_0.h265?dl=0. If a different input is required the `nalUnits` array will need to be re-generated for the new input file.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

extern "C" {
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
}

const std::string input = "data\\stream_0.h265";
const std::string output = "data\\stream_0_out.mp4";

const struct nalUnit
{
    int start;
    int size;
    const long long pts;
} nalUnits[] = {
    {0, 27, 0}, {27, 67, 0}, {94, 14, 0}, {108, 10091, 0}, {10199, 6571, 0}, {16770, 5021, 0}, {21791, 614, 40000},
    {22405, 392, 40000}, {22797, 432, 40000}, {23229, 490, 80000}, {23719, 281, 80000}, {24000, 434, 80000},
    {24434, 488, 120000}, {24922, 220, 120000}, {25142, 314, 120000}, {25456, 420, 160000}, {25876, 233, 160000},
    {26109, 405, 160000}, {26514, 513, 200000}, {27027, 284, 200000}, {27311, 401, 200000}, {27712, 512, 240000},
    {28224, 243, 240000}, {28467, 355, 240000}, {28822, 407, 280000}, {29229, 277, 280000}, {29506, 381, 280000},
    {29887, 372, 320000}, {30259, 245, 320000}, {30504, 365, 320000}, {30869, 444, 360000}, {31313, 230, 360000},
    {31543, 385, 360000}, {31928, 444, 400000}, {32372, 236, 400000}, {32608, 315, 400000}, {32923, 398, 440000},
    {33321, 304, 440000}, {33625, 300, 440000}, {33925, 465, 480000}, {34390, 159, 480000}, {34549, 371, 480000},
    {34920, 382, 520000}, {35302, 241, 520000}, {35543, 357, 520000}, {35900, 338, 560000}, {36238, 152, 560000},
    {36390, 278, 560000}, {36668, 442, 600000}, {37110, 256, 600000}, {37366, 355, 600000}, {37721, 418, 640000},
    {38139, 207, 640000}, {38346, 379, 640000}, {38725, 334, 680000}, {39059, 210, 680000}, {39269, 349, 680000},
    {39618, 330, 720000}, {39948, 260, 720000}, {40208, 346, 720000}, {40554, 372, 760000}, {40926, 247, 760000},
    {41173, 316, 760000}, {41489, 284, 800000}, {41773, 228, 800000}, {42001, 265, 800000}, {42266, 405, 840000},
    {42671, 229, 840000}, {42900, 369, 840000}, {43269, 349, 880000}, {43618, 330, 880000}, {43948, 237, 880000},
    {44185, 411, 920000}, {44596, 192, 920000}, {44788, 278, 920000}, {45066, 397, 960000}, {45463, 235, 960000},
    {45698, 335, 960000}, {46033, 27, 1000000}, {46060, 67, 1000000}, {46127, 14, 1000000}, {46141, 10130, 1000000},
    {56271, 6612, 1000000}, {62883, 5110, 1000000}, {67993, 584, 1040000}, {68577, 368, 1040000}, {68945, 388, 1040000},
    {69333, 512, 1080000}, {69845, 223, 1080000}, {70068, 375, 1080000}, {70443, 465, 1120000}, {70908, 265, 1120000},
    {71173, 431, 1120000}, {71604, 464, 1160000}, {72068, 278, 1160000}, {72346, 445, 1160000}, {72791, 368, 1200000},
    {73159, 245, 1200000}, {73404, 377, 1200000}, {73781, 449, 1240000}, {74230, 248, 1240000}, {74478, 386, 1240000},
    {74864, 491, 1280000}, {75355, 226, 1280000}, {75581, 328, 1280000}, {75909, 403, 1320000}, {76312, 223, 1320000},
    {76535, 454, 1320000}, {76989, 457, 1360000}, {77446, 272, 1360000}, {77718, 371, 1360000}, {78089, 431, 1400000},
    {78520, 253, 1400000}, {78773, 303, 1400000}, {79076, 397, 1440000}, {79473, 294, 1440000}, {79767, 366, 1440000},
    {80133, 405, 1480000}, {80538, 253, 1480000}, {80791, 394, 1480000}, {81185, 361, 1520000}, {81546, 273, 1520000},
    {81819, 344, 1520000}, {82163, 386, 1560000}, {82549, 239, 1560000}, {82788, 353, 1560000}, {83141, 395, 1600000},
    {83536, 279, 1600000}, {83815, 340, 1600000}, {84155, 449, 1640000}, {84604, 199, 1640000}, {84803, 366, 1640000},
    {85169, 381, 1680000}, {85550, 267, 1680000}, {85817, 317, 1680000}, {86134, 412, 1720000}, {86546, 251, 1720000},
    {86797, 320, 1720000}, {87117, 325, 1760000}, {87442, 226, 1760000}, {87668, 270, 1760000}, {87938, 438, 1767511},
    {88376, 215, 1767511}, {88591, 255, 1767511}, {88846, 336, 1807511}, {89182, 224, 1807511}, {89406, 290, 1807511},
    {89696, 372, 1847511}, {90068, 236, 1847511}, {90304, 278, 1847511}, {90582, 389, 1887511}, {90971, 189, 1887511},
    {91160, 286, 1887511}, {91446, 405, 1927511}, {91851, 244, 1927511}, {92095, 280, 1927511}, {92375, 27, 1967511},
    {92402, 67, 1967511}, {92469, 14, 1967511}, {92483, 10136, 1967511}, {102619, 6585, 1967511},
    {109204, 5051, 1967511}, {114255, 639, 2007511}, {114894, 354, 2007511}, {115248, 416, 2007511},
    {115664, 523, 2047511}, {116187, 322, 2047511}, {116509, 414, 2047511}, {116923, 454, 2087511},
    {117377, 295, 2087511}, {117672, 474, 2087511}, {118146, 502, 2127511}, {118648, 290, 2127511},
    {118938, 359, 2127511}, {119297, 476, 2167511}, {119773, 283, 2167511}, {120056, 440, 2167511},
    {120496, 404, 2207511}, {120900, 279, 2207511}, {121179, 348, 2207511}, {121527, 470, 2247511},
    {121997, 225, 2247511}, {122222, 381, 2247511}, {122603, 420, 2287511}, {123023, 274, 2287511},
    {123297, 300, 2287511}, {123597, 389, 2327511}, {123986, 296, 2327511}, {124282, 405, 2327511},
    {124687, 408, 2367511}, {125095, 300, 2367511}, {125395, 311, 2367511}, {125706, 378, 2407511},
    {126084, 246, 2407511}, {126330, 433, 2407511}, {126763, 383, 2447511}, {127146, 270, 2447511},
    {127416, 344, 2447511}, {127760, 434, 2487511}, {128194, 229, 2487511}, {128423, 351, 2487511}
};

const size_t fileLength = 128423+351;

const AVRational timebase = { 1,1000000 };

bool LoadInputFormat(AVFormatContext*& inputFormatContext)
{
    int ret;
    // create an AVFormatContext object using the video file. This can be used
    // to query information such as sample aspect ratio of the input file.
    if ((ret = avformat_open_input(&inputFormatContext, input.c_str(), nullptr, nullptr)) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Error: Unable to open input file: " << input.c_str() << ". Error code: " << ret <<std::endl;
        return true;
    }

    // search the file for stream info and add to the context
    if ((ret = avformat_find_stream_info(inputFormatContext, nullptr)) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Error: Unable to find stream info: " << input.c_str() << ". Error code: " << ret <<std::endl;
        return true;
    }

    av_dump_format(inputFormatContext, 0, input.c_str(), 0);
    return false;
}

unsigned char* ReadData()
{
    FILE* f;
    if (fopen_s(&f, input.c_str(), "rb") != 0 || f == nullptr)
        return nullptr;
    auto* const data = new uint8_t[fileLength];
    size_t index = 0;
    while (index < fileLength) {
        const auto count = fread(data + index, sizeof uint8_t, fileLength - index, f);
        std::cout << "read " << index << "+" << count << " - " << fileLength << std::endl;
        index += count;
    }
    return data;
}

int Initialise(const std::string& outputFile, AVCodecParameters* encoderParameters, AVFormatContext*& outputContainer,
               AVStream*& outStream)
{
    auto ret = avformat_alloc_output_context2(&outputContainer, nullptr, nullptr, outputFile.c_str());
    if (!outputContainer || ret < 0) // both check for error. Should always be consistent
    {
        std::cout << "Error: Unable to open output file: " << outputFile << " Error code: " << ret << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    outStream = avformat_new_stream(outputContainer, nullptr);

    if (outStream == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "Error: Unable to create video stream for output file" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    if ((ret = avcodec_parameters_copy(outStream->codecpar, encoderParameters)) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Error: Unable to initialise writer context. Error code: " << ret << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    outStream->sample_aspect_ratio = encoderParameters->sample_aspect_ratio;

    if ((ret = avio_open(&outputContainer->pb, outputFile.c_str(), AVIO_FLAG_WRITE)) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Error: Unable open output for writing: " << outputFile.c_str() << ". Error code: " << ret <<
            std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    if ((ret = avformat_init_output(outputContainer, nullptr)) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Error: Unable to initialise output. Error code: " << ret << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    av_dump_format(outputContainer, 0, outputFile.c_str(), 1);

    if ((ret = avformat_write_header(outputContainer, nullptr)) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Error: Unable to write header for output. Error code: " << ret << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int WritePacket(const nalUnit& nalUnit, unsigned char* const data, AVFormatContext* outputContainer, AVStream* outStream, int64_t& lastRawPts, int64_t& lastPts)
{

    AVPacket packet;
    auto ret = av_new_packet(&packet, nalUnit.size);
    if (ret != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Error: Unable to allocate packet: " << ret <<std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    memcpy(packet.data, data + nalUnit.start, nalUnit.size);
    std::cout << nalUnit.start << " "<<(int)packet.data[0] << " " << (int)packet.data[1] << " " << (int)packet.data[2] << " " << (int)packet.data[3] << std::endl;
    const auto pts = av_rescale_q(nalUnit.pts, timebase, outStream->time_base);

    if (lastRawPts == pts)
        packet.pts = packet.dts = ++lastPts;
    else
        packet.pts = packet.dts = lastPts = lastRawPts = pts;
    packet.duration = 0;
    packet.stream_index = 0;
    packet.flags = 0;
    packet.pos = -1;

    if ((ret = av_write_frame(outputContainer, &packet)) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Error: Unable to write frame. Error code: " << ret << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    av_packet_unref(&packet);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    AVFormatContext* inputFormatContext = nullptr;
    if (LoadInputFormat(inputFormatContext))
        return -1;

    auto* const data = ReadData();
    if (data == nullptr) return -1;

    AVFormatContext* outputContainer;
    AVStream* outStream;

    auto ret = Initialise(output, inputFormatContext->streams[0]->codecpar, outputContainer, outStream);
    if (ret != 0)
        return ret;

    avformat_close_input(&inputFormatContext);

    int64_t lastRawPts = -1;
    int64_t lastPts = -1;
    for (const auto& nalUnit : nalUnits) {
        ret = WritePacket(nalUnit, data, outputContainer, outStream, lastRawPts, lastPts);
        if (ret != 0)
            return ret;
    }

    ret = av_write_frame(outputContainer, nullptr);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Error: Unable to flush frames. Error code: " << ret << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    av_write_trailer(outputContainer);
    avio_closep(&outputContainer->pb);

    if (outputContainer)
        avformat_free_context(outputContainer);

    return 0;
}
```

I am compiling in Visual Studio 2019 with ffmpeg version 4.4.1 from [www.gyan.dev](http://www.gyan.dev) (https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/7e0d640edf)

I have tried ensuring that the read codec parameters do not include the metadata frames and messing with the timestamps (so that all the slices have the same pts but not dts) but with no progress.

Any help would be apprecianted. Thanks!

Comment: Does the CLI tool give the same result?

Comment: I have no idea how to provide individual nal units directly to the CLI tools, but the nearest I can do is `ffmpeg -i stream_0.h265 -c:v copy stream_0_cli_out.mp4` does work and doesn't show the issue.